# Problems with IE10 and DevExpress CallbackPanel

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, internet-explorer-10

Ok, so here is the issue we are having. We have a website that uses a DevExpress callback panel. We have gotten calls from users using IE10 that the page is blank.

I setup a machine with IE10 - to try and replicate the problem. When logging into the production website, I saw the same thing – the page is blank, except that you can see an empty SpitterControl up in the top left corner (indicating a control with nothing in it). I checked the f12 developer tools, all of the markup is there. Also, when going to quirks mode, or IE9 mode, page renders fine.

So good so far. The next step is to replicate the issue in my local environment so I can throw in some breakpoints and try to find the cause. Here is where I am stumped. Local dev environment no issue at all; Page renders fine in IE10. I am running IIS7 on my machine with the same .NET framework.

So, on to the next step. We have a machine where we stage code for beta testing – its configuration basically mirrors the production configuration. Same result, all IE10 pages rendered just fine.

I have kind of run out of ideas. I have of course researched the doctype, and forcing the IE9 mode. All things that I could try, but I just puzzled by the fact that all of my testing environments I could not get it to break.

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q474930 - if this helps

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S38642.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I have already checked those. I know of the workaround. Just trying to figure out why I can't replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up an offsite dev setup. It could be that within your domain. I know that in one case we had problems with devexpress controls loading out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - well work around anyways. Setting the  worked. It just wasn't so simple to just make a change like that to the production database - but I finally got it in there to try it. Jeez.. what a pain!

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package option from this link worked for me so I assume that installing the hotfix on the server would also work:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

SUMMARY:

- Make sure you have NuGet installed
- Right click on project then click on Manage NuGet packages
- Search Online for "App_BrowsersUpdate"
- I installed the one for .net 4
- Republish